# Twilio group video call android

Tags: android, twilio

I want to create group video calling android app and using twilio service for video calling.

I am trying to add all participant video on sigle screen.

Any one know can single VideoView can handle multiple videotrack or i have to create VideoView for each videoTrack(as shown in https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-android).